# How to execute mvn command using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-2, maven-3

I am trying to add Oracle JDBC driver in my local Maven repo. I have found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/) link to do so.

I want to do the same from Inside IntelliJ IDEA. Is there any way to execute mvn commands from IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: there is no need to execute the command via intellij , executing the `install-file` via command line gives you the same result

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There is a button in maven menu of Intellij IDEA:

[image: screenshot]

Also you can always use "Terminal"

Comment: Very useful option, when you need pass -U flag to force refresh bundled maven

Comment: The maven menu is visible in the "Maven Projects" Tool Window" - you find it here: IntelliJ main menu: View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects. You can assign a shortcut to it, e.g. Alt+8

Comment: how to start mvn -version from this button ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow you cannot run 'mvn -version' from here, it's not a "goal"

Comment: In terminal it says "The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet". I couldn't find a mvn.exe anywhere

Comment: @MikeKulls https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: @RuslanOstafiichuk yes thanks, but Maven is somewhere as Intelli J can use it. Not sure why I couldn't find it at the time but a simple search found it now. I do have a new machine since then. Maybe I was searching for mvn.exe, I can't remember.

Answer (score 36):

Just press the ctrl key twice!

Then you will see this:
[Command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dmrt.png)

Then run your maven command

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html

Comment: What a solution! :)

Comment: Examining the output of the `mvn --version` command lends clues to this: `MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3`

Answer (score 13):

You can check the Image :

[image]

If you don't fine the Maven Projects there then you can open it from Bottom Left part of Intellij IDEA, there's one Square Button there. click on it.

If You don't have `configure the maven` path then you also need to configure maven directory also. Using `maven settings`.

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.2 (maybe earlier) there is a maven projects tool window:

[image: Maven Tool Window]

Then goals are available:

[image: Maven Goals]

There is no other way than to use the terminal for some commands.
But these are few since there is quite a number of cool features in the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

In the Edit Configurations you can specify a Maven configuration which allows you to execute Maven goals.

That said, I recommend to add the library to a Maven Repository such as Nexus. Then you can use the library like any other dependency and don't have to wory about the local repositories yourself.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to create configuration for one execution

Comment: It's one way to do it, maybe not the best in this case true. But again, I recommend not to go down this path anyway.

Answer (score 3):

[image: The maven command image is updated as below(in the latest versions)]

A popup will come up on clicking the maven icon from where mvn commands can be executed.

Comment: No such "M" icon in the toolbar of the Maven panel in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2. I wonder if it has been replaced by the little terminal-screen icon named *Execute Maven Goal*?