# Where is the input history for Maven commands stored in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, input-history

I've [executed a Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27246065/2936460) command through the built-in command line interface in IntelliJ.

[image: Execute Maven Goal]

It was in another project than my current one. I can't find the command in the history for the input. However, the input provides a drop down for previous commands.
Additionally, I'd like to be able to (selectively) delete command from the history.

**Where is that history stored?** Is that per project? If so, where?
And how can I delete entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm halfway there. I've found the history, it's indeed stored per project, in `.idea/workspace.xml`, under `/project/component[@name='mavenExecuteGoalHistory']`. I can manually delete it from there as well.

Now to find the key combination to do that from that dropdown...

Comment: Write a plugin (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/maven/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/idea/maven/navigator/actions/ExecuteMavenGoalHistoryService.java), or use Maven Helper plugin.