# Run Maven commands (other than "Lifecycle" goals) from within IntelliJ 2019

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, terminal, console

In IntelliJ 2019.3 Ultimate, I am working with a Maven-based project. I never installed Maven on my Mac. So I am using only the Maven bundled inside the IntelliJ app.

The *Maven* panel within IntelliJ displays several "Lifecycle" Maven goals such as `clean` and `install`. These work well. So this Question is *not* a duplicate of: [*How to execute mvn command using IntelliJ IDEA?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27246065/642706).

I read about using other Maven commands such as this:

```bash
mvn dependency:tree | grep "guava"
```

This does work from my Apple Terminal.app with error since I have no Maven installed separately:

> zsh: command not found: mvn

This does not work from the *Terminal* window within IntelliJ:

> zsh: command not found: zsh:

➥ So how does one run other Maven commands such as `mvn dependency` using the Maven built into IntelliJ?

Comment: You should check if you have installed the "Maven Helper" Plugin...Afterwards click on the pom file which shows the pom file as XML and there is tab below the pom file named "Dependency Analyzer" which shows you a full tree of dependencies...also look at the docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html Plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper/

Comment: Just to make this precise: A command chain as the one you mentioned is _not_ a Maven goal/phase, but a unix-like command line command. `grep` is not run by maven, but by whatever command line interpreter you have. You can, though, use parameters to `dependency:tree` that allow you to filter for certain dependencies. Please also consider the advice of khmarbaise.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the right most corner marked as *Maven*. Then click the `m` icon. I provide below the image.

After that, you can write Maven commands like `mvn dependency:tree`. That covers the Maven-specific part of your command example. The pipe to `grep` will not work here.

Besides, if you want you can use Maven wrapper just like Gradlew(Gradle warapper), in this case there is no need to install maven and you can build from the command prompt.

[image]

Comment: Partially works. I can run `mvn dependency:tree`. But running `mvn dependency:tree | grep "guava"` with the piping results in error: `Unknown lifecycle phase "|"`

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote. This Answer is a partial solution, and is helpful.